# get all results from couchbase full text search rest API with no limit

Tags: rest, full-text-search, couchbase

I want to get all the results from a full text search index in couchbase. However, the default limit is 10 results.

I am aware that I can customize the size to a specific number, but is it possible to set it such that I get all the results in one go?
Something like `"size":"*"` or `"size":"all"`

```
curl -u user:password -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"query": {"query": "search_token"}, "size": 10}' \
http://1.2.3.4:8094/api/index/myindex/query
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like there's an "all" option for size. Omitting size falls back to 10.

I tried using a really large number, and got an error message:

```
{
    "error": "rest_index: Query, indexName: ix_myindex, err: bleve: bleveMaxResultWindow exceeded, from: 0, size: 999999999, bleveMaxResultWindow: 10000",
    "request": {
        "query": {
            "query": "search_token"
        },
        "size": 999999999
    },
    "status": "fail"
}
```

So, 10000 is the max you can ask for by default.

According to Couchbase ticket [MB-17539](https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/MB-17539), you can increase the maximum:

```
curl -XPUT -H "Content-type:application/json" http://<username>:<password>@<ip>:8094/api/managerOptions -d '{"bleveMaxResultWindow": "100000"}'
```

I tried this, and it works. However, I don't see this endpoint in the documentation so it might change/become deprecated in the future.

But, I really have to wonder why you need this many results at once? Is paging not an option for you? (e.g. a body of `{"query": {"query": "search_token"}, "size": 10, "from": 10}`).

Comment: The reason for this is that each search result item correspondence to thousands of couchbase documents. I know this seems unintuitive and it is. It has to do with how we currently are storing our data. Eventually we will have to change our habit in the future.